# How to get the DOM element of the block in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

How can I access the DOM of my block in Gutenberg? I need to get the render width of the block.

```
import { createRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit(props) {   
    let rootBlockRef = createRef(null)
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({...props, ...rootBlockRef})
    console.log(rootBlockRef)

return [
<div ref={rootBlockRef} {...blockProps}>TEST</div>
];
}
```

Tried document.querySelector but returns null.
Also tried createRef, useRef but also returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) inside your `Edit()` function. It's called after each render, so the `rootBlockRef` should be accessible in there. Note it has to be imported from `@wordpress/element`.

Comment: Thanks you! That works!
I had data attributes in the div of my "actual code" that for some reason cause the ref not to work. maybe that would save someone a few hours...